# RegEx to match a single digit followed by a "." followed by another single digit

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find the RegEx in use with the preg_match function for a single digit followed by a "." followed by a single digit.

Example:

3.3 valid
44.4 invalid but would capture 4.4
4.664 invalid but would capture 4.6

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted an an atempt or two.

Comment: what do you mean `invalid but would capture` either it's valid and captures or invalid and does not capture.  It either matches or it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this regex should help you:

`\d{1,1}[\.]{1}\d{1,1}`

you can try other regex at [this site](http://www.regextester.com/?fam=95922)

Comment: why so verbose? `[\.]{1}` is just a waste of cpu/space when `\.` would do, as is `{1,1}`

Comment: how would you get string(input) validity from this? it would match 4.4 out of 44.4,

Comment: Awesome! it words exactly as i wanted it to! thank you!

Comment: @MarcB just to be more robust, and than he can change to `,` anytime
@nogad take a look at the link I had posted
@BradB nice =D, please accept my answer and give me upvote =D

Comment: @nogad it works exactly the way of @BradB asked, he wants something to pick 1 number before and 1 number after the dot... doesn't matter if has others numbers before or after.. tha's why  `44.4` you pick `4.4` and `4.664` you pick `4.6`

Comment: I think the point was that this `/^\d\.\d$/` will do the same thing.  https://regex101.com/r/MKGZz0/1

Comment: well i think your the only one who interpreted the question that way, looked like he wanted string validation to me true\false.